# TFS Build Agent skipping all tests

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, build-agent

I've set up a build controller and build agent for my TFS 2012.
I have a .NET 4.0 project with coded UI tests that I would like to run there.
I set the build configuration to run with VS Test Runner.

The problem is that the test runner skipping all of my tests!
(I can see `Skipped <test_name>` for all my tests in the log view when I run the build with Diagnostic logging verbosity)

Any ideas?

**update -**

I've googled a lot on this and found that adding a `.testsettings` file in the build configuration should solve this, but when I added one, the build fails with the following error (found nothing about this error :( ):

> MSTestAdapter could not run the test as the classic mode is not available. Reason: Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation. 
>   Directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors does not exist

and with this warning:

> No tests is available in . Make sure that installed test discovers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Answer (score 2):

To run coded ui test in build server, you needed to run the build agent as an interactive process (Build service property, Run as Interactive Process), you also need setup a test controller and an interactive test agent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181712.aspx#interactive

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127.aspx

in your testsettings you can sepcify the testagent and other settings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx